# When can 'almost' be used instead of 'almost like'?

Tags: sentence-patterns

1. Jack is almost like a father to me.
2. Jake is almost a father to me.
3. My aunt almost sounds foreign.
4. My aunt almost sounds like foreign.

Why can't I write **Jake is almost a father to me** instead of **Jake is almost like a father to me**? If second sentence is wrong, what do you think about fourth? Is it correct? The first and third one have been collected from *Practical English Usage* by Swan. According to the discussion (that will be discussed by the experts of this site about the questions stated above), what will be the correct form of following sentence?

5. Our cat understands everything almost like human.
6. Our cat understands everything almost human.

Comment: Your questions seem better suited to or sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in these six sentences.  The first is the difference between the copulative verbs (verbs of being, seeming, and sensing) and non-copulative verbs (verb of acting, for want of a better term).  The second is the use of *like* as a preposition.

The second, first:  *like* requires an object, e.g., a noun or a noun phrase.  An adjective won't do.  Thus "like a foreigner" is fine since "a foreigner" is a noun phrase.  But "like foreign" won't do since *foreign* is an adjective.

For copulative verbs, the **subject** can be described by an adjective or equated to a noun.  These are called the nominative *complement*.

> **John** is a *father*.
>   My **aunt** sounds *foreign*.
>   My **aunt** seems *foreign*.
>   My **aunt** seems a foreigner.

Verbs of sensing allow only adjectives as complements.  Nouns turn them into verbs of action.  So "My aunt sounds a foreigner" won't work.  In this case, English has no sense for *sounds* in this way, but try it with a different sense:

> My **aunt** smells *good* because she wears jasmine perfume.

That fits the template, but for

> My aunt smells fish because that's what's cooking in the oven.

*fish* is the direct ***object*** of the active verb *smells* and tells us not about the state of your aunt but of her action in the same way that *understands* tells us about the action of your cat.  So you can say

> My **cat** understands ***humans***
>   My **cat** understands almost all ***humans***

An adjective is not available as a direct object any more than it is available as the object of a preposition like *like*, so

> My **cat** understands human

is ungrammatical with the active verb, but

> My **cat** seems *human*

is fine with the copulative verb.

Both types of verb may be modified by prepositional phrases, so it's possible to say

> Jack is like a father.
>   My cat is like a human.

Note the nouns as objects of the preposition.  Finally consider the following sentence:

> My aunt smells like a fish.

This is ambiguous.  In the awful case that *smells* is a verb of sensing, then it seems that your aunt has been using herring for a fragrance, which means

> My **aunt** smells *fishy*.

In the case that *smells* is a verb of action it means that your aunt picks up odors the same way a fish does.  Which may be only marginally better.

Comment: Wow. You wrote a huge answer laced with ambiguities just to spite me? I had no idea copulative verbs meant _that_. And all those aunts smelling like fish, that's positively medieval.

Comment: *Copulative* means linking.  And you had me at "I had no idea."  The rest is just talking past the close.  And don't flatter yourself.  I write answers to please myself.  I would be interested in what you think is ambiguous though.

Comment: You would, wouldn't you.

Comment: Yes, indeed I would.

Comment: Mannerisms of elocution aside, you'd do well to toss some rep points my way. Remember, I still need more of them to gain the "pay the ELU maoists in kind" privilege. I nearly always throw some your way, not that you need any more of them.

Comment: OK, upvote for "tough room."  That was a good answer.  And I am not the downvote on your answer here.  I've never downvoted you.

Comment: All my answers are superb. As for the other thing, say what? You've got your foibles and whims, but I've never doubted your decency, duchess.

Answer (score -2):

The first one is wrong:

*Jack is almost like a father to me.*

You should use either almost or like, not both.

The second one is correct:

*Jake is almost a father to me.*

Nothing wrong here. The following two are both wrong:

*My aunt almost sounds foreign.*
*My aunt almost sounds like foreign.*

The correct way to write this is:

**My aunt sounds almost foreign.**

The following two are questionable no matter how you scramble them:

*Our cat understands everything almost like human.*
*Our cat understands everything almost human.*

The first one is missing an article; the correct way to write it would be:

**Our cat understands everything, almost like a human.**

It is questionable because for these reasons:

1. No human can understand everything
2. "Everything" means everything. I doubt anyone's cat could understand Shakespeare or Puccini.

It's not totally and completely wrong only because, even though cats are stupid, some humans are even more so.

Finally, this one:

*Our cat understands everything almost human.*

- means, in fact, that the cat is capable of understanding anything that's almost human. Which is puzzling, since, while it is easy to pinpoint things that are human, as well as not human, some people would have a hard time thinking of something that's "almost human."

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cats are stupid, are they?  My cat could write a better answer than this.  Starting with the fact that there's nothing wrong with "Jack is almost like a father to me."  Jack isn't quite like a father, but he's close.

Comment: @deadrat: Of course it can. But can it mambo? What good is a cat that can't mambo? As for the other thing. I'm not a great fan of phrases such as "seems like" "almost like" and so forth. I don't _like_ them, if you will. "He's almost like a father to me" isn't merely redundant. It's moronic. I don't care how many people mindlessly use the expression, nor how many of them get paid for using it. If you think real hard about it (or maybe discuss it with your superintelligent cat), you'll realize that "He's almost like a father to me" is actually an insult.

Comment: A cat that can't mambo is exactly as good as one that can.  The following questions may be interesting:  Does Ricky like the phrasing?  Is its use mindless?  Is its use moronic?  Are people being paid to use it?  Is it redundant?  Is it insulting to Rickys everywhere?  But the questions the OP wants answered are "Is it grammatical?" and "If so, why?"

Comment: @dearat: I wouldn't mind, actually. There would be a lot less platitude in the world; folks would be more attuned to the finer things in life; and Philistines would do what they're supposed to do: make sausages (instead of running governments and opera companies, as they do today). My answer is explicit, to the point, succinct, pithy, and astoundingly useful. Your answer is meandering, needlessly convoluted, and ultimately confusing.

Comment: Don't capitalize *philistines*. The Philistines are long dead.  Your answer is explicit, to the point, succinct, and wrong.  If after consideration, you're sure that it's my answer and not you that's confused, please tell me what I should fix.

Comment: Shaw does (in ... uh ... _Man and Superman_, if I recollect aright). But thanks for reminding me. I'm going to turn it into a question (not the capitalization part). I retract the confusing part. Your answer is brilliant. They should put it in all textbooks.